# Core bluetooth peripheral.name is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I just want to have the list of nearby Bluetooth devices' names. However, `peripheral.name` is always nil. The name in Advertising package is also always nil. I have 7 devices nearby. I can see them but not their names.

I am using following code:

```
[self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]]
                                            options:nil];


- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI

{

    NSLog(@"Discovered %@ at %@", peripheral.name, RSSI);
    _discoveredPeripheral = peripheral;
    if(![self.mRemoteDevices containsObject:_discoveredPeripheral])
    {
        NSArray *peripherels = [self.centralManager retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:@[_discoveredPeripheral.identifier]];
        [self.mRemoteDevices addObject:[peripherels objectAtIndex:0]];
        [self.mRemoteTable reloadData];
    }
    NSLog(@"retrieving peripherels: %@", self.mRemoteDevices);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure but may be You have to pass options like this. @{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]} instead of nil. It has many options. I have use like that.

Comment: Try to not connect until you don't have a name or an advertisement data. If I remember correctly, these info are coming piece by piece and may then appears each time a new piece of info came. By you may have to change the allow duplicates key parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It often happens indeed that the peripheral names are not resolved during discovery. However, after you've discovered a peripheral (and maybe connected to it, I'm not sure if this is truly necessary), you'll soon receive its proper name in `CBPeripheralDelegate` callback `- peripheral:didUpdateName:`. Assuming that prior connection to the peripheral is not necessary, you should just wait for this callback and update the name of a proper device in your `mRemoteDevices` in the callback code.